# Improving speed of queries/processing of RegExp function with two database tables

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, regex

I have a program with a function that retrieves a relatively short text string from one SQL database table ("html"), runs a number of regular expression queries on it, and then stores the output in another database table ("profiles").  "Html" has about 8 million records and "profiles" stores only the results.  It is currently very slow - well over 1 second per record on a fast server.  I'm hoping someone might be able to point out something obvious that I would be able to fix:

```
dataComm dc = new dataComm(@"SERVER1", "html");
dataComm dc_bp = new dataComm(@"SERVER1", "profiles");

Int32 numinserted = 0;

for (int selectc = 0; selectc < 85000; selectc++)
{
  DataTable dt = dc.fetchData("SELECT top 100 * from html where processed=0");

  label3.Text = "Iteration " + selectc + " of 85,000";

  string sq="";
  string squpdate = "";

  Int32 thisid=0;

  for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
  {                    
    // CODE THAT RUNS THE REGULAR EXPRESSIONS.
    thisid = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ID"]);

    sq += @"INSERT INTO profiles (field1, field2, [etc.]) VALUES ('value1','value2', [etc.]); ";
    numinserted++;

    squpdate += "UPDATE html SET processed=1 WHERE ID=" + thisid.ToString() + "; ";
  }

  dc.executeNonQuery(squpdate);

}
```

Comment: Do you know the relative time for each part of the routine: i.e. is the problem with the RegExp calls, the `INSERT` execution (is that missing?), or the `UPDATE` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SQL 2005+, you can build some CLR to execute regular expressions in SQL. Very handy. Rather fast. Then, you can handle everything in SQL and push your code towards set-based operation rather than looping.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be simply not running regular expressions on that HTML but parse it in some other way, e.g. with the [HTML agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Parsing HTML with regex is "bad", doing a lot of it is very "bad". (It will depend on the regex, but they can be written so that they are really inefficient for this task.)